# Keeping watermark at the top most layer - as3/flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a set up that looks something like:

```
<mx:Canvas>
   <mx:Image id="mayimage"/>
</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Button id="watermark"/>
```

Where the button is the watermark that I want to keep on top of the image.

But after loading the actual image dynamically using addChild into "myimage", the skin of the button(which is embeded using @Embed) is covered up by the new image.

The weird thing is, it looks fine in Firefox, where the watermark button is still on the very top layer, it only gets covered up in Chrome.  Also, the button is still clickable even though it's covered by the image, meaning only the skin of the button is covered...

Anyway of keeping the skin of the button on the very top layer?

Comment: Try to manually set the child index,  like this.setChildIndex(watermark, this.numChildren-1) after loading the image

Comment: Using `addChild()` on an object already on the stage brings it up to the top automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `addChild` to display your image, just change the `source` property of `myimage`.

Comment: Example looks like Flex 3 MX Halo - visual elements are Flex 4 Spark.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider this:

```
<mx:Canvas id="myCanvas">
   <mx:Image id="mayimage"/>
</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Button id="watermark"/>
```

and you use `myCanvas.addChild(myImage)` the image will never overlap the watermark. Are you by any chance adding it to the upper level `canvas`?